# Silverlight control to group other controls together for data binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Is there a control in silverlight to group controls together for data binding.  For instance, say I have a Person object and I want to display fname, lname, age, height, etc. in TextBlocks.  Is there a control I can use to group these TextBlock controls together and set the ItemSource on just that control similar to how you set the ItemSource on a DataGrid and then bind each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any of these answers is correct, however I don't think will work/are appropriate for my app.  The MVVM approach is overkill for my app and the other two approaches will not work for me for various reasons.  I will just do everything in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

Group the TextBlocks in any layout control and bind the control's DataContext to Person. If not explicitly set, each TextBlock's context will be relative to the parent.

```
<UserControl DataContext="">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <SomeViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ThePerson}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding fname}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding lname}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding age}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding height}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

View model class...

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public Person ThePerson { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: Then how do you bind the Grid to a specific instance of Person?

Comment: Are you binding to Person in your view now? How? Maybe you can clarify a little better what you're trying to accomplish. Are you looking for a reusable control or just a way to logically organize the binding? Do you have just one Person or a collection?
The assumption in my answer is you have a public property Person on the UserControl's DataContext. With MVVM, that data context would be a view model. I updated the code to better demonstrate.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you're looking for. This answer would provide a way to group binding for related textblocks (a ContentControl with a DataTemplate would work the same way).

If your looking for a separate UserControl to encapsulate this, look into Ben's answer.

If you have a collection of Persons, look into an ItemsControl like ListBox and set the DataTemplate. Items in the DataTemplate will be similarly relative.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this article on MVVM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

It sounds like you need to create a "PersonView" and a "PersonViewModel" (and probably a "PersonCollectionViewModel")
This would allow you to bind the controls on your "PersonView" (A Silverlight UserControl) to the "PersonViewModel".

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataForm control and set its "IsReadOnly" property to True ,this control usually used to edit data, and remember to set AutoGenerateFields="True" ...

PS : I'm supposing you're using Ria service with silverlight